# Make generic class "re-infer" the generic params after method call

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I don't know how to explain this or how this feature is called in Typescript, but let's look at an example.

Pretend that we could use the below class to map an object to another

```
class Mapper<TFrom, TTo> {
    from(obj: unknown): this // implementation does not matter for now
    to(type: Class<TTo>/*this should receive a constructable type signature*/): this
    transform(): TTo
}
```

How can we infer TFrom and TTo after method calls instead of the `new` initialization?

```
class Person {
   name: string
}
const personObj = {name: 'test'}
const personInstance = new Mapper().from(obj1).to(Person).transform()
```

For the code above to have the correct type `Person` on `personInstance` I would need typescript to infer `TFrom` and `TTo` after `from()` and `to()` method calls respectively, otherwise the only way for it to work the way it is now is to pass the types as arguments to the `Mapper` constructor like this:

```
const personInstance = new Mapper<typeof obj, Person>().from(obj1).to(Person).transform()
```

Is there any way to achieve something like it?

The only way I can think of is to force `from` and `to` methods to return Another Mapper instance correcly typed instead of `this`, but that would require the `from` method to have a generic type argument as well and this would get messy:

```
from<TFromFn>(obj: TFromFn){
// ...
return this as unknown as Mapper<TFromFn, unknown>
}
```

Thanks for reading this far!

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBhANgQwM54A8AKgHwIC8CA3ggHYgDuCAFAJQBcCxCAvgNzAh4aPAQBjXAQQBZHBDQwSAMRhQAtgBpuxKOWrAERhBDVwQ48wBMEAMzXqAajiwBXEAEIuxVRsGHjUyhzSxAbOChiVBAAfi5sfCJiXVJ-YzsHFQdSFnsNZzcQb191Tll5RSyNbWS9GgD0ozgACwBLPAA6PKcXd0oM-N6QQUbjGBA4Vxg6JDa8BHwFumQR414hdIiSFJYIqLR4qSSUsrkFECUfBxqU+tGmuY696P7ntFXR8cnp2faF+Zwyw+fCEDQQYLgMEBeFssHU7G8uju9y+UxmADcoK0bAAGf5LZBg9bpYDrISSRIIAAKFzwUBmBmMdBw6k8XDwkNadAA5qTgOJ6RyTLT6QB5ABGACt+tRmayuABycwchXrAV0IWKOl0ACSGrggPE6CoDGYZ0U7C6DhYWrFUrYTygLBpMG1Dsh0NhMHhbGAAHo-ekAHoxCSCxC23X6w1FakiujAIA)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the details of the question, it does not really seem like the generic type `TFrom` is needed since you are not using it anywhere.

You are right in assuming that the methods need to be generic too. If we only have the `TTo` type than only `to` needs to be generic.

```
class Mapper<TTo> {
    from(obj: unknown): this {
      return {} as any
    }
    to<TTo>(type: new () => TTo): Mapper<TTo> {
      return {} as any
    }
    transform(): TTo {
      return {} as any  
    }
}
```

`personInstance` would now have the correct type.

```
class Person {
   name!: string
}
const personObj = {name: 'test'}
const personInstance = new Mapper().from(personObj).to(Person).transform()
//    ^? const personInstance: Person
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyYAcEFMBOAeAKpg9gPmgG8AoaM6AM1RwFsAKHAIwCsAuaAVwDsBrLnAO5cAlOwAuACwCWMEuXKpkYjqi5EAvtEhauAT1Ll1BsmJxZceOmN0p2XZAOh1h0ALwFsOUXEQoMngjl5aEVlVQ0tGDA9Y2gjeTFUaIgKHFR6b08iWLJQlTVCTW1o3TJYoyNiYlBIGAAFNAgcAuMuMBpkAEJ2CESpLgBzYiNgZt7oPyauAHkWNyI2jvYAcjFkXuWRsbEJxuaASS5e6OBkeftHeCQ0ZwA6Klo6SebZ5mFb0zoG1Cn3xOTUulnMQAPQg%20QAPQA-NBRkcds8uIdjlxTuxvlMgA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it indeed types the `personInstance` correclty but it gives me some errors on my actual implementation, I modified a bit the playground to looks more like the actual scenario I have and Added on the question (too long for the comment). The error makes me think if this is the right aproach, also esLint gives me the no-shadow complain